# PHP success message on same page / styling

Tags: php, html, css, forms

I am new to PHP but found a tutorial for a php contact form. the form works well except the 'your email was sent successfully' text shows on a new page.

Is there a way to make it so the text shows on the same page?

I am also unsure how I would go about styling the information?

thanks

```
<?php


$to = 'zoeharrisondesign@gmail.com';
$subject = 'New Message Recieved!';
$from = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$name = $_POST['name'];

//check honeypot
    if( !empty( $honeypot ) ) {
        echo 'There was a problem';
    }
 
// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
 
// Create email headers
$headers .= 'From: '.$from."\r\n".
    'Reply-To: '.$from."\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
 
// Compose a simple HTML email message
$message = "$message \r\n |
                From $name \r\n |               
                Tel: $phone";


 
// Sending email

if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
    echo 'Your mail has been sent successfully.';
} else{
    echo 'Unable to send email. Please try again.';
}

?>
```

HTML

```
<form role="form" action="action.php" method="post" class="contact-form">   
            
<div class="form-row"><input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="name" required="required"></div>
                        
<div class="form-row"><input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="email" required="required">  </div>
                        
<div class="form-row"><input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="phone"></div>
                        
<div class="form-row"><textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="message" required="required" style="height:200px"></textarea></div>
                        
<div class="form-row" style="display:none;">
<input type="hidden" name="url" placeholder="URL"></div>
                        
<div class="form-row"><input class="submit" type="submit" value="Send"></div>   
</form>
```

Comment: Can you add the code that redirects to the other page? I assume you have a form that has an action that points to another page yes?

Comment: i dont think so, my html is just a standard form, theres no reason i can see as to why its taking me to another page other than the PHP

Comment: Can you add the `form` tag, is there an `action` attribute in your form tag? PHP does not arbitrarily pass you to another page without being coded with a header redirect or action attribute in your form tag. Something in your code is redirecting you to another page...

Comment: Change `<form action="NEW_PAGE_LINK">` to `<form action="">`

Comment: Where is `$honeypot` defined?

Comment: <form role="form" action="action.php" method="post" class="contact-form">

Answer (score 0):

An easy way of doint that is using **sessions**,
you need to create a session php file like just this:

**SESSION.PHP**:

```
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1);
session_set_cookie_params(0,'/','localhost',false,false); // IF YOU ARE HOSTING IT IN LOCAL 
session_start();
session_regenerate_id(); // REGENERATE SESSIONE FOR SECURITY ISSUES
```

**MAIL PHP FILE**:

```
// add this on top of your mail.php file 
include 'session.php'; // just insert the path of the file
// AND CHANGE THIS
if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){ 
   $_SESSION['error'] = 'Your mail has been sent successfully.'; // setting your session and value
   header("Location: index.php"); // path of the file where you want to show the text
   exit();
} else{
   // same thing 
}
```

**INDEX.PHP**: (just add this where you want to show the text, example:)

```
 if(isset($_SESSION['error'])) {
   echo '<h1>'.$_SESSION['error'].'</h1>';
   unset($_SESSION['error']); // to display it just once and then delete it 
 }
```

***IMPORTANT***: you need to add also `<?php include 's-session.php'; ?>` to the top of your index.php file

Answer (score 0):

```
In top of php code start the session`session_start();`
```

Insert this piece of code

```js
if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){   
$_SESSION['message'] = "Submitted Successfully";
}
```

Paste this code in html where you want to show the message

```html
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['message'])): ?>
      <div class="msg text-success" id="success" >
      <?php 
        echo $_SESSION['message']; 
        unset($_SESSION['message']);
      ?>
      </div>
    <?php endif ?>
```